# MS-Access Ошибка обновления подчиненной формы

Tags: vba, ms-access

На форме `frmTransportation` есть подчиненная форма `[Form_подчиненная форма qryTransportationByTransport]`. После удаления строки из таблицы которая служит источником для подчиненной формы, не обновляется подчиненная форма. Ошибка на строке `.Requery`

> Ошибка 3420  Object is invalid or no longer set

если в окне нажать Debug и вручную продолжить трассировку, то дальше код выполняется, но в подчиненной форме все значения заменяются на `#имя?`
Как решить проблему?

Код кнопки

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click()
    Dim ID As String
    Dim curRecSOurce As String
    ID = IIf(IsNull(tbIDHidden), "", tbIDHidden)
    If ID <> "" Then
        If MsgBox("Удалить запись о перевозке " & _
                    [Form_подчиненная форма qryTransportationByTransport].Destination & _
                    " от " & [Form_подчиненная форма qryTransportationByTransport].Data_ & " ? ", _
                    vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM tblTransportation where Код = " & ID
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True

        With [Form_подчиненная форма qryTransportationByTransport]
            If .RecordSource <> "qryTransportationByTransport" Then
                .Form.RecordSource = "qryTransportationByTransport"
            End If
            DoCmd.Requery [Form_подчиненная форма qryTransportationByTransport].Name
            .Recalc
            .Repaint
        End With
        tbIDHidden = vbNullString
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
    With [Form_подчиненная форма qryTransportationByTransport]
        If .RecordSource <> "qryTransportationByTransport" Then
            .Form.RecordSource = "qryTransportationByTransport"
        Else
            .Requery
        End If
    End With
```

Замена RecordSource всегда делает также Requery

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Проблему изначально была неверно идентифицирована. Подчиненная форма отображает данные по критерию комбобокса. Если комбобокс пустой, источник строк подчиненной формы давал сбой. Я же тестировал так: сначала добавляль новую строку в таблицу (с очисткой полей ввода) и сразу же хотел удалить строку кнопкой. Но тк комбобокс очистился то источник строк подчиненной формы валился.